# sql query result returns asterisk "*" as column value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to update a temporary table with multiple values from another table without using a join. 
However, the query doesn't give any error but rather returns an asterisk as the value of the column. I have googled and asked some folks around the office but no one seems to have encountered this before or can offer explanation of why this could be happening.

```
update ##tempCLUnique set Total = 
(
    select COUNT(distinct u.unique_subs)
    from tbl_Cluster_Cumm_Unique_Subs u
    where u.cluster = ##tempCLUnique.cluster
)
```

Seems simple enough

[Result Screen Grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE0ER.png)https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE0ER.png

Comment: What datatype is the column `Total` in the temp table.

Comment: Which tool are you using(in screenshot)?

Comment: Tool is SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: Hpw will an `UPDATE` show the result same as `SELECT`?

Comment: If the column was a `char` or `varchar` this could happen. Are you really sure it is an integer? What does the query look like that you use to do a select from the temp table?

Comment: @CliffordPabs-Garnon can you provide sqlfiddle

Comment: @CliffordPabs-Garnon: As I wrote before, how can an `UPDATE` show results? Moreover, can you try changing the output to be sent to text instead of grid?

Comment: Fixed it, @MikaelEriksson hit on something I missed in 1 previous sql. It was a datatype mismatch issue. Simply added convert(numeric(18,0),0) as Total

Comment: @shahkalpesh Pardon my description. I used select statement to see the results of the update

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why cast/convert from int returns an asterisk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124055/why-cast-convert-from-int-returns-an-asterisk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
update ##tempCLUnique set Total = U.unique_subs

FROM ##tempCLUnique
INNER JOIN
(
    select COUNT(distinct unique_subs)unique_subs
    from tbl_Cluster_Cumm_Unique_Subs 

)U

ON

 u.cluster = ##tempCLUnique.cluster
```

Change the join according to your use.

Ashutosh

Comment: Results are the same as before. "*" is inserted into ##tempCLUnique

Comment: I am also looking for the reason this is occurring so I can understand the problem as well

Comment: @CliffordPabs-Garnon if `*` is as you say **inserted** then you do **not** have an integer column. Either the value is converted to `*` when you add it to a char/varchar column or you convert the value to char/varchar when you query the table.

Comment: @CliffordPabs-Garnon What is the result from this script `select COUNT(distinct unique_subs)unique_subs
    from tbl_Cluster_Cumm_Unique_Subs`

Comment: try elecuting     select COUNT(distinct u.unique_subs)
    from tbl_Cluster_Cumm_Unique_Subs u
    where u.cluster = ##tempCLUnique.cluster
alone what are you getting please update

Comment: @CliffordPabs-Garnon, I tried to build similar kind of query it worked fine, please try elecuting this, if it gives a similar kind of error on your machine may be you need to reinstall your sql server {CREATE TABLE ##TEMP (ID BIGINT,COL_CNT VARCHAR(10))


INSERT INTO ##TEMP SELECT DISTINCT ID,NULL FROM SYSCOLUMNS

update ##TEMP set COL_CNT = 
(
    select COUNT(distinct u.name)
    from SYSCOLUMNS u
    where u.ID = ##TEMP.ID
)

SELECT * FROM   ##TEMP}