# Why does 9+1 = * , and how can I fix it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm having trouble with my database because its got auditing worked in and things are hard. I need to compare the current change with the last change so I thought I'd include a grouping column. But when I run my code, some of the column values are *. It goes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,* . What the ... idon'tevenknow ?

This is what I'm doing:

```
DECLARE @Person char(11), @DonationYTD decimal(10, 2), @OldPerson char(11), @OldDonationYTD decimal(10, 2), @Group int;
SET @Group=1;
DECLARE TempCursor CURSOR FOR Select PersonID, DonationYTD FROM MyTable;
OPEN TempCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM TempCursor INTO @Person,   @DonationYTD ;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    IF( @Person != @OldPerson)
        SET @Group=1;
    IF(  @Person = @OldPerson AND @DonationYTD!=@OldDonationYTD)
        SET @Group=@Group+1;
    UPDATE MyTable SET CHANGEGROUP=@Group WHERE PersonID=@Person AND DonationYTD=@DonationYTD;
    SET @OldPerson = @Person;
    SET @OldDonationYTD = @DonationYTD;
    FETCH NEXT FROM TempCursor INTO @Person,  @DonationYTD ;
END
CLOSE   TempCursor;
DEALLOCATE TempCursor;

SELECT PersonID, DonationYTD, Changegroup FROM MyTable

1   15.00   1
1   15.00   1
1   20.00   1
2   3.00    1
2   4.00    2
2   15.00   3
2   8.00    4
2   4.00    5
2   15.00   6
2   3.00    7
2   3.00    7
2   9.00    8
2   9.00    8
2   10.00   9
2   14.00   *
2   14.00   *
```

If I try to do anything with Changegroup it tells me it can't convert varchar symbol * to integer.
Why am I getting an asterisk? How can I fix it?

Comment: Change group seems to be a `char(1)` or similar and you are inserting a string of length 2 into it.

Comment: I just realized that you are right! That's the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering the issue [described here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530(v=sql.105).aspx)

> When integers are implicitly converted to a character data type, if
>   the integer is too large to fit into the character field, SQL Server
>   enters ASCII character 42, the asterisk (*).

From which I deduce your column must be `[var]char(1)`. This odd behaviour does not occur for the newer n[var]char types, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10060736/73226).

The fix would be to change the column datatype. Ideally to a numeric datatype such as `int` but if it must be string at least one long enough to hold the intended contents.