# Try_convert issue * sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why am I getting `*` in the result where I have two digits.?

```
Declare @Product TABLE(id int identity(1,1),Cust VARCHAR(25), 
                        Product VARCHAR(20), QTY INT)

INSERT INTO @Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','VEG',2),
      ('KATE','SODA',6),
      ('KATE','MILK',1),
      ('KATE','BEER',12),
      ('FRED','MILK',3),
      ('FRED','BEER',24),
      ('KATE','VEG',3)


select *,TRY_CONVERT(varchar(1),QTY) qty1 from @Product
```

Comment: Because that's the [documented behaviour](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)? "Conversions to char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, binary, and varbinary are truncated, except for the conversions shown in the following table." - `int`- `*`.

Comment: Perfect i got it now from all who have answered and given in comments. thanks every one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the resulting datatype is too short to display. As per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

> **Truncating and Rounding Results**
>
> When you convert character or binary expressions (char, nchar,
> nvarchar, varchar, binary, or varbinary) to an expression of a
> different data type, data can be truncated, only partially displayed,
> or an error is returned because the result is too short to display.
> Conversions to char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, binary, and varbinary
> are truncated, except for the conversions shown in the following
> table.

This happens when you convert from  `int , smallint, or tinyint` to `char /varchar`

Answer (score 4):

You have only specified a single character in your `TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), QTY) qty1`.

If you change it to `VARCHAR(2)`, it will work:

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE
    (
      id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      Cust VARCHAR(25) ,
      Product VARCHAR(20) ,
      QTY INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @Product
        ( Cust, Product, QTY )
VALUES  ( 'KATE', 'VEG', 2 ),
        ( 'KATE', 'SODA', 6 ),
        ( 'KATE', 'MILK', 1 ),
        ( 'KATE', 'BEER', 12 ),
        ( 'FRED', 'MILK', 3 ),
        ( 'FRED', 'BEER', 24 ),
        ( 'KATE', 'VEG', 3 )


SELECT  * ,
        TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), QTY) qty1
FROM    @Product
```

I'm not sure why you would want to convert the `QTY` to a `VARCHAR` though as it's an `INT`. The size would have to increase if you had a `QTY = 200`.

The reason you see `*` is due to [truncation of values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) that are too large for the specified datatype as mentioned by @Damien_The_Unbeliever in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744249/try-convert-issue-sql-server-2012#comment47621415_29744249).

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are explicitly trying to convert it to `varchar(1)`, write as below and it will work:

`select *,TRY_CONVERT(varchar(2),QTY) qty1 from Product`

If you want to convert `int,Float,Real` values to varchar use [STR()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) instead as it enables more control over formatting.
`STR()` function is defined for approximate numeric (float) data type with a decimal point which in turn is rounded to an integer by default.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68bcd9/1)</kbd>

Comment: This actually answers OP question

Answer (score 1):

The query returns a * because sql server returns * whenever an integer is converted to (var)char and its length is smaller than specified. You can solve your issue by casting to a varchar(2) instead. See this post
[Why cast/convert from int returns an asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124055/why-cast-convert-from-int-returns-an-asterisk) for more information why SQL returns a * instead of raising in error. In short, this seems to be legacy behaviour.