# Execute mathematical expression and set the value to variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Mathematical expression expression created from three variable @val1,@val2 and @Operator. So should I need to execute the query by string and I need to set the value of the variable inside the query string, how can I set?

I Tried Below

```
declare @val1 varchar=100;
declare @val2 varchar=300;
declare @Oper varchar(20)='>';

declare @query varchar(max);

declare @Flag int=0;

set @query='if(convert(int,'+@val1+')'+@Oper+'convert(int,'+@val2+') set @Flag=1';


exec (@query);
print @Flag;
```

**Note:**
  I am Using this inside the function.

Comment: You cannot execute dynamic sql in UDFs, if that is your intention

Comment: Remove the convert functions and just concatenate the three strings. You are building a query string. The execute command will worry about the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parametrized query with `sp_executesql` procedure:

```
DECLARE @val1 VARCHAR(20)= '500';
DECLARE @val2 VARCHAR(20)= '300';
DECLARE @Oper VARCHAR(20)= '>';

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @Flag INT= 0;

SET @query = 'if ' + @val1 + @Oper + @val2 + ' set @Flag=1';

DECLARE @ParamDefs NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'@Flag int output'

EXEC sp_executesql @query, @ParamDefs, @Flag OUTPUT

PRINT @Flag;
```

Also corrected some mistakes:

1. `declare @val1 varchar=100;` Default size will be `1` and `@val1` is initialized with `*` not `100`. See [Why cast/convert from int returns an asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124055/why-cast-convert-from-int-returns-an-asterisk) for details.
2. You don't need to cast to `int` inside dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the,

```
declare @val1 varchar=100; 
declare @val2 varchar=300; 
declare @Oper varchar(20)='>';
```

To

```
declare @val1 varchar(100)
declare @val2 varchar(300)
declare @Oper varchar(20)='>'
```

Comment: If you are using this multiple times then only create this as function otherwise you can directly write the code in Stored Procedure and pass parameter to Stored procedure.