# Parameters are not taken by execute statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute the below given code, the execute statement is not taking those parameters.

**What is the other way to use those parameters for execute statements?**

```
DECLARE @ver nvarchar(128)

SET @ver = CAST(serverproperty('ProductVersion') AS nvarchar)

SET @ver = SUBSTRING(@ver, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @ver) - 1)

SELECT @ver



DECLARE @chvCpuCount AS VARCHAR(256)

DECLARE @bintMemory AS BIGINT


IF @ver < 11

Execute('SELECT @chvCpuCount = cpu_count

, @bintMemory = (physical_memory_in_bytes / 1048576)

FROM master.sys.dm_os_sys_info')

else

Execute('SELECT @chvCpuCount = cpu_count

, @bintMemory = (physical_memory_kb / 1048.576)

FROM master.sys.dm_os_sys_info')

SELECT @chvCpuCount, @bintMemory
```

Thanks !

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233495/execute-mathematical-expression-and-set-the-value-to-variable-in-sql/30233620#30233620

Comment: When you have a char-string like `' .... @chvCpuCount ...'`, the `@chvCpuCount` is not a variable in your script it is a variable in the char-string script, So declaration and other operation to that variable will goes inside that char-string ;).

Comment: Ok. How can I edit my code to get executed

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use dynamic SQL for this. Just do

```
IF @ver < 11

   SELECT @chvCpuCount = cpu_count, @bintMemory = (physical_memory_in_bytes / 1048576)
   FROM master.sys.dm_os_sys_info

else

   SELECT @chvCpuCount = cpu_count, @bintMemory = (physical_memory_kb / 1048.576)
   FROM master.sys.dm_os_sys_info
```