# Is there a better/alternative way to write a query that accepts an arithmetic operator than using dynamic SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic

I'm writing a stored procedure where I have to update a quantity of specific product ( obviously I can either increase or decrease it). Since the only difference is an operator value( + or - ) I'd like to use the same procedure in both cases. I know this question was already answered here - [Execute mathematical expression and set the value to variable in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233495/execute-mathematical-expression-and-set-the-value-to-variable-in-sql) , but it doesn't help me because they wrote it in MSSQL. Anyone knows how can I do it in MYSQL? Is it right , the following code is the best solution if I write in MYSQL ?

```
BEGIN

SET @foundID = -1,@name=name, @company=company;
SET @number=number, @action=plusMinus;
CALL spCheckIfProductExists(@name,@company,@foundID);

IF (@foundID != -1 AND (@action='+' OR @action='-'))
 THEN SET @sql = concat("UPDATE instock SET quantity = quantity",@action , " @number WHERE productid= @foundID");
 PREPARE update_statement FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE update_statement;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE update_statement;
END IF;
END
```

This is a working code but I know it's a very bad practice to concatenate strings when I write dynamic stored procedure. Any ideas how to improve it ?

Comment: `UPDATE table SET value = value + ((condition) * 2 - 1) * delta`, where `condition` is your boolean expression. If `condition` is TRUE, it is treated as 1, and you obtain `UPDATE table SET value = value + delta`. If `condition` is FALSE, it is treated as 0, and you obtain `UPDATE table SET value = value - delta`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change sign of @number variable by @action value

```
BEGIN
  SET @foundID = -1, @name = name, @company = company;
  SET @action = plusMinus;

  CALL spCheckIfProductExists(@name, @company, @foundID);

  IF (@foundID != -1 AND (@action='+' OR @action='-')) THEN
    IF (@action='-') THEN
      SET @number = number;
    ELSE
      SET @number = -number;
    END IF;
    SET @sql = concat("UPDATE instock SET quantity = quantity + ? WHERE productid = ?");

   PREPARE update_statement FROM @sql;
   EXECUTE update_statement USING @number, @foundID;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE update_statement;

  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is controlled by a [*whitelist*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/whitelist) and *is not used to fill a value context* (which is better handled differently), it is “okay” to use dynamically generated SQL *because* the resulting SQL statement is controlled.

***However, dynamic SQL is a large hammer that adds unnecessary complexity here.***

In the “-” action case, simply *multiply the value by -1 (read: change the sign) before using it in a placeholder or variable context* and then always use + as the action: “quantity + x” or “quantity + (-x)” are both valid. This special-case would not apply to other operators such as “*”.

```
SET @adjustment = CASE WHEN @action = '-' THEN -@number ELSE @number END

UPDATE instock SET quantity = quantity + @adjustment
WHERE productid = @foundID
```

Even when allowing other operators, this could still be done with a ‘CASE @action WHEN ..’ and eliminate the dynamic SQL generation, as MySQL itself would perform different processing based on the action, and the action itself is only specified where a *value* is allowed.

```
 UPDATE instock
 SET quantity = (CASE @action
     WHEN '*' THEN quantity * @number
     WHEN '-' THEN quantity - @number
     WHEN 'e' THEN 2.71828
     ELSE quantity + @number
   END)
 WHERE productid = @foundID
```

Building SQL strings dynamically is generally only required when the shape of the query changes and, in many cases, approaching the query in an problem-specific manner often leads to cleaner solutions..