# CHECKSUM_AGG(checksum()) returns stars (**********)

Tags: sql-server, hash, hashcode, checksum

I am calling

```
id int ,
tableid int,
seid int,
ptid int,
VISID NVARCHAR(50),
Tname AS SYSNAME ,
ColumnValue NVARCHAR(50),
ColumnKey NVARCHAR(50),
@HashValue NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT

select @HashValue = CHECKSUM_AGG(checksum(id,tableid, seid, ptid, VISID, Tname, ColumnKey, ColumnValue))  from #FDATA
```

When #FDATA contains:

> 17    3028    100 100003  SCRN    form.LG_AE  320  InvInit
>
> 17    3028    100 100003  SCRN    form.LG_AE  321  AuthIn
>
> ......... (6 rows in total with similar data, no null values)

it returns **********

But when #FDATA contains:

> 17    3019   101  101001  SCRN  form.LG_AE   320   InvInit
>
> 17    3019   101  101001  SCRN  form.LG_AE   321   AUTHIn
>
> ...... (65 rows in total with similar data, no null values)

It returns an integer as expected

Comment: Sorry you don't give us enough information to recreate your problem, please provide a minimally complete question, include table structures and enough data that shows your problem.

Comment: According to documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-agg-transact-sql)) it returns `int`. What type is variable `@HashValue`?

Comment: DECLARE @HashValue int

Comment: And when you are selecting `@HashValue` it returns stars? Could you provide more information (maybe full data if it is possible)?

Comment: @Rokuto some times it returns stars and some times returns integer . I cant post full data, they are similar with ones I provided. the only thing that differs is the number of the rows

Comment: I've found similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124055/why-cast-convert-from-int-returns-an-asterisk). Check it. How are you selecting `@HashValue`? Are you casting it to `varchar`?

Comment: I print it like this: print str(@HashValue) and there I see the stars or the correct value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124055/why-cast-convert-from-int-returns-an-asterisk) and comments, function [`STR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql) returns `*` because the number, which is stored in `@HashValue` variable, exceeds the specified length (default 10). Instead of `STR` use `CAST`, for example:

```
PRINT CAST(@HashValue as varchar(20))
```

or just print value without casting it:

```
PRINT @HashValue
```

or use function `STR`, but with length parameter:

```
PRINT STR(@HashValue,20)
```