# Incorrect value inserted into SQL server table when inserted value is greater than column length

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

**Situation:**

I have an existing legacy table [dbo].[Values] which sits on SQL server 2017.

In this table I have 3 columns.

- int tableid (Primary Key)
- char (8) code
- char (7) description

Code and description are both custom data types but both are just char (8) ,char (7) with no additional logic.

**Action**

If I insert into this table where the inserted value to column code is greater than 8 char's I get * inserted into that column.

No error or warning is given.

I have looked in triggers, constraints, policies, the table's creation script, custom datatypes. I cannot find any where there is logic that says if truncate set value = *

**Question**

What part of sql server would modify values before it is saved into the table?

Comment: Can you duplicate the table (i.e. create a [dbo].[Values2] using the same DDL) and try what happens there? Just to make sure there is nothing that somehow escaped your analysis so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why cast/convert from int returns an asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124055/why-cast-convert-from-int-returns-an-asterisk)

Comment: @stickybit - Not really. The question "Why does this happen?" and the answer "Because X" is a different Q from asking "I know the product does X. Why was it designed that way"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would see this if you are also using the incorrect datatype and getting an implicit cast from `int`.

```
CREATE TABLE #T(C CHAR(8))

INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1111111111);

SELECT *
FROM #T
```

It is [documented behaviour here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#truncating-and-rounding-results)

Solution. Use a string

```
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('1111111111');
/*String or binary data would be truncated.*/
```

This is [legacy behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10060736/73226) that is unlikely to change

Comment: This is exactly what had happened - I found more information on :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#truncating-and-rounding-results