# ISNULL prints *

Tags: sql-server, isnull

I am encountering this strange behavior (Okay maybe not strange but beyond my understanding) when using isnull. It all sums up to this:

`isnull(left(cast(null as varchar),1),0)`  gives `0`

`isnull(left(cast(null as varchar),1),-1)` gives `*`

I would like to know the reason behind this behavior.

Although I got a workaround here:

```
select isnull(cast(left(cast(null as varchar),1) as varchar),-1)
```

Comment: [Why cast/convert from int returns an asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9124055/15498)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. I need to learn to expand my search criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the asterisk is due to an overflow error. `left(cast(null as varchar),1)` would return a `varchar(1)`. Within the `ISNULL` the value `-1` would be implicitly converted to a `varchar(1)`, and a negative number cannot be represented with a single character, hence why an `'*'` is displayed.

If you change it to a `LEFT(...2)` then get a result:

```
SELECT ISNULL(LEFT(CAST(NULL AS varchar),2),-1);
```

On a different note [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: That Explains it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(left(cast(null as varchar),1),-1);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=497ffb34b2d68e9467baa5ebad69f42b)**

`ISNULL` infers data type from first argument, `COALESCE` infers from wider one([Data type precedence](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=497ffb34b2d68e9467baa5ebad69f42b))

Comment: I understand null inferring data type from first argument. I also know about COALESCE. What I wasn't understanding was *. Got that from Larnu's answer. Thanx for the Explaination